# Marks Calculator

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I keep getting syntax error highlighted on "m" in second row on the variable "mark2".
This is the code I have:

```
print("Please enter your 5 marks below")

mark1 = float(input("enter mark1: ")
mark2 = float(input("enter mark2: ")
mark3 = float(input("enter mark3: ")
mark4 = float(input("enter mark4: ")
mark5 = float(input("enter mark5: ")
marksList = [mark1, mark2, mark3, mark4, mark5]
print(marksList)
sumofMarks = mark1 + mark2 + mark3 + mark4 + mark5
averageOfMarks = sumofMarks/5
print("The sum of your mark is: "+str(sumofMarks))
print("The sum of your mark is: "+str(averageOfMarks))
```

Comment: Missing `)` (in next 4 lines as well)

Answer (score 0):

```
mark1 = float(input("enter mark1: "))
                                    ^ you missed this
```

In the next 4 lines as well. It is better to use an IDE (Eg: PyCharm) to catch these errors.